# How to find out diagonal difference in go programming?

Tags: go, slice

My code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
    s := make([][]int, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &s[i][j])
        }
    }
    s1 := 0
    s2 := 0
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
            if i == j {
                s1 += s[i][j]
            }
            if i+j == n-1 {
                s2 += s[i][j]
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(s1 - s2)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

I tried but get panic. I want to know proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
s := make([][]int, n)
```

Creates a slice of slices, a slice whose elements are of type `[]int`. It creates a slice with `n` elements, but the elements of the outer slice are initialized with the zero value of the element type, and zero value of type `[]int` is `nil` (just like for any slice type).

You get `index out of range` panic because any element of the outer slice `s` has zero length (because they are not initialized to a non-`nil` slice), so `s[i][j]` panics for any `j` value.

If you want to assign elements to the "inner" slices, you also have to initialize them:

```
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    s[i] = make([]int, n) // YOU ARE MISSING THIS LINE
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%d %d", &s[i][j])
    }
}
```